# Single URL mod_rewrite keeps going back to the original URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a very simple single URL rewrite.

This is it:

```
RewriteRule ^blog /?post_type=post [NC,L]
```

I would simply like `example.com/?post_type=pos` to redirect and display `example.com/blog`.

I have tried a number of different versions of the rewrite but all I have achieved thus far is that I don't get a 404 on `example.com/blog` but keeps going back to `example.com/?post_type=post`.

I have placed `RewriteRule` right at the top of the `.htaccess` file which didn't help.

These are the other rewrites I have in the same `.htaccess` file:

```
#Single URL
RewriteRule ^blog ?post_type=post [NC,L]

#http www rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instrumentrentalbarcelona.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.instrumentrentalbarcelona.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @DocRoot for helping me with this. The answer is detailed in the comment thread below by DocRoot and I. Just thought I would summarise this.

- I wanted to show a page with all my blog posts.
- This can be done if you use the WordPress post type "Post". `example.com/?post_type=post`
- I wanted that page to show when you go to `example.com/blog`.
- The following Rewrite works to show the desired URL: (thank you again @DocRoot)

  ```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post_type=post$
  RewriteRule ^$ /blog [QSD,R,L]
  ```
- But `/blog` was giving a 404. So;
- Create a page in WordPress called "blog"
- Go to: Setting > Reading > Your homepage displays > Posts page: [Select page "blog"]
- Save and done.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog /?post_type=post [NC,L]
> ```
>
> I would simply like `example.com/?post_type=pos` to redirect and display `example.com/blog`

The directive you posted does the exact opposite. It "rewrites" (not "redirects") from `/blog<anything>` to `/?post_type=post`

To redirect based on the *query string* you need an additional *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable because the URL that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is the URL-path only.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post_type=post$
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [QSD,R,L]
```

This "redirects" from `example.com/?post_type=post` (exactly) to `example.com/blog`.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the redirected request. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then you will need to append the *substition* with `?` instead of using the QSD flag. eg. `RewriteRule ^$ /blog? [R,L]`.

Not also, this is a temporary (302) redirect. If this should be permanent, then change the `R` flag to read `R=301` - but only once you have confirmed this is working OK.

Comment: Thank you @DocRoot ! Not sure I understand this 100% but I tried it out. My server is on Apache 2.4+ 

This makes the /?post_type=post go to /blog. Progress but the page is broken?

Comment: If the page is "broken" then presumably accessing `/blog` directly is broken? In what way is it "broken"?

Comment: Apologies should have included this: https://www.screencast.com/t/1VESbupMr5JM

There is no actual directory, assuming that it is rewrite so there does not need to be a folder?

Comment: The screenshot shows a redirect loop. That would not seem to be possible given the directives above? Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? Have you cleared your browser cache? Presumably you are getting the same error when requesting `/blog` directly?

Comment: I manage to resolve the loop (silly mistake I had the old script in different part of the .htaccess file). 

I tested removing everything from .htaccess except what you see above and replacing my single URL code for the code you sent me:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post_type=post$
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [QSD,R,L]

Now the /blog is showing a 404. You can view it all here: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iXoasPhpX5Vmf7Srhv-xwgOWpNFSarPfdgstkIaonLU/edit?usp=sharing

thank you again

Comment: This redirect must go _before_ the WordPress front-controller. (The same place you had it in your question.)

Comment: I did have that before, but still the same thing. I have moved it back to the top. in example and also on the actual .htaccess. I get the same result.

Comment: "still the same thing" - as in a 404? Does it redirect? What do you get if your request `/blog` directly?

Comment: I've just tried this on your site and the redirect seems to be working OK. The problem would seem to be that the `/blog` URL is invalid and needs to be defined in WordPress? If `/blog` doesn't route to a valid page on your site then this is never going to be successful?

Comment: Thank you for time and patience. Yes I am still getting 404. My understanding is that the valid page is /?post_type=post and then the new URL /blog is simple a rewrite to make the /?post_type=post URL look prettier. If I remove this rewrite and put /?post_type=post you will see all the blog posts: https://www.screencast.com/t/ofJlpsGN6fNb (is this not the valid page?)

Comment: Solved: I created a page called /Blog. I then Changed the setting in WordPress to show post on this page. 

Setting>Reading>Your homepage displays>Posts page: [Select " Blog" Page Created]

Implemented your original rewrite and it works perfectly.